# Express body-parser gziped json not turning into object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, body-parser

I am trying to send gzipped json to a nodeJS/Express server but I cant get it to work, in production I am using some code to gzip a json object and send that up but for testing purposes I have it running with curl

My Express app is just a normal express 4 application using the body-parser module:

```
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use('/', routes);
```

And is using the cluster module:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;
    for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
} else {
    var app = require('../app');
    var debug = require('debug')('Test:server');
    var http = require('http');
    var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
    app.set('port', port);
    var server = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen(port);
    server.on('error', onError);
    server.on('listening', onListening);
}
cluster.on('exit', function (worker) {
    cluster.fork();
});
```

With a route:

```
router.post('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    try{
        console.log("body: " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
        console.log(typeof req.body);
        console.log(req.body.data);
        return res.send("Ok");
    }catch(err) {
        return res.send("Failed to process: " + err);
    }
});
```

If I make a post with curl

```
curl --request POST --data '{"data":[{"foo":"bar"}]}' --header "Content-Type: application/json" -v 127.0.0.1:3000/test
```

I get the expected:

```
body: {"data":[{"foo":"bar"}]}
object
[ { foo: 'bar' } ]
```

If I read from a file:

```
curl --request POST --data '@uncompressed.json' --header "Content-Type: application/json" -v 127.0.0.1:3000/test
curl --request POST --data--binary '@uncompressed.json' --header "Content-Type: application/json" -v 127.0.0.1:3000/test
```

I get a response:

```
{"message":"invalid json","error":{"body":"{\"data\":[{\"foo\":\"bar\"}]}","status":400}}
```

The contents of the file being:

```
$ cat uncompressed.json
{"data":[{"foo":"bar"}]}
```

And if I try to make a curl with compressed data:

```
gunzip -c -d compressed1.dat
{"data":[{"foo":"bar"}]}
curl --request POST --data-binary '@compressed1.dat' --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Content-Encoding: gzip" -v 127.0.0.1:3000/test
```

I get the same 400 as before, a 400 being what my code is receiving when sending up compressed data..

So far the only way I have been able to accomplish what I want is to use body-parser text/raw which returns `{"data":[{"foo":"bar"}]}` as the req.body with a type of string and use `var body = eval( "(" + req.body + ")" )` to then turn it into a json object, but this is dangerous as anyone could send up some js in the request and hijack the server..

Comment: post the code that is outputting "invalid json", you are almost certainly JSON.stringifying a string that is already json

Comment: Its the bodyParser.json() here is the code https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser